# Correctly registering services in Xamarin.Forms app with Prism

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm, prism, inversion-of-control

I am building a Xamarin.Forms application and have decided on using the Prism MVVM framework with Unity as the IoC. It is my first time using Prism, I have been using MVVMLight for my previous app. I liked how Prism looked and felt so I just went with it.
As I was building the application I kept adding services be it platform specific or regular services. Every service I would register inside the `RegisterTypes` method override inside the `App.xaml.cs`.

As I did when using MVVMLight, all of my services got registered like `containerRegistery.Register<IService, Service>()`. But after adding base view models (with common services being injected), and building on the app, everything started to feel very slow when using the app, every tap to navigate took 2-3 seconds to load without seeming to do anything. I noticed that it happened only when navigating.

I built a demo base view model with a couple of pages to see if it was the framework's problem, or something else, but after seeing the instant navigation I started to dig a little further. Turns out it was the service injection from the base view model.

The thing is, when I changed all of my service registration to `containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IService, Service>()` everything is back to buttery smooth.

My question is, why is that? I know that using only `Register` builds a new instance every time, but I have been successfully using it like that in MVVMLight. And is it a good way to register the services as `RegisterSingleton`?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `RegisterSingleton` makes sense, because there is no reason to have multiple copies of each service. I assume from the performance issue, that Prism is not as efficient as mvvmlight, when there are multiple instances for each service. I don't think there is anything more to it than that. Though it is surprising that it slowed down enough to notice.

Comment: I'll also comment that anything that is naturally a singleton, such as a service, can be cached in a `static` variable, of some base or helper class. If you do so, then `Resolve` only happens once - regardless of the number of instances of view models. This does the IoC injection once, during app startup. After that, there is negligible overhead to accessing the service. Its almost as if you did `public static IMyService MyService = new MyService();` - but with the IoC advantage that the base class doesn't know the implementation class. And without adding instance members to your VMs.